# "Self" not defined when trying to use self in instance variable within class

Tags: python

Let us say I have code like this

```
class A:
  var1 = self.var0

  def __init__(self, var0):
    self.var0 = var0
```

how might I get self.var0 into var1 without putting var1 inside the init function?

Comment: What do you expect `self` to be at that point?  Why don't you want to put it in `__init__`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options that I can think of:

1) Include it in the init function if you want an A object to be created with A.var1=var0:

```
class A:

  def __init__(self, var0):
    self.var0 = var0
    self.var1 = self.var0
```

2) If you really don't want var1 inside of the init function, you could create a function that is part of the A class like so:

```
class A:

  def __init__(self, var0):
    self.var0 = var0

  def setVar1(var1):
    self.var1 = var1
```

Then to create an A object and set its v1 value equal to v0, you would do something like this:

```
v0 = some_value
a = A(v0)
a.setVar1(v0)
```

**Edit:**

3) As suggested by "Blckknght" in the comments on one of the other answers: You can chain assignment statements:

```
self.var0 = self.var1 = var0
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
class A:

  def __init__(self, var0):
    self.var1 = self.var0 = var0
```

However, I do not see much point in this and would rather simply initialize it immediately like so:

```
class A:

  def __init__(self, var0):
    self.var1 = var0
```

If you wish to have two variables with the same value, stick with the first method.

Comment: You can also chain assignments: `self.var0 = self.var1 = var0`

Comment: Yeah, sure. Good Idea, I will add that.

Answer (score 0):

In your code `var1 = self.var0` is at class-level, not at instance-level, so `self` doesn't make sense here. To see it, try this:

```
class C(object):
    field1 = 1

    def __init__(self):
        self.field2 = 2

print(C.field1)
print(C.field2) # should raise an exception
instance = C()
print(instance.field1) # not found in instance but found at upper level (class-level)
print(instance.field2)
```